# How to insert the data in the middle of donut chart using kedo

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement the kendo donut graph using angular 2. I got stuck in inserting the data in the middle of the donut. If any one has a solution can you post some examples?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you get stuck you should show what you have tried so far. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. [Here are some hints](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: In classic KendoUI based on jquery the best soulution would be use Kendo Drawing API. Unfortunately Kendo for Angular 2 does not have it. So you should try to use separate container with your data, displayed centerd on top of the chart.